# Best way to share an Excel with an ODBC connection?

Tags: microsoft-excel, odbc

What's the best way to share within local network any Excel file that uses ODBC?

I guess any user must define the ODBC connection locally in order to reload the data.
Is there a way to dump an extract of data that updates automatically?.

I'm lost. How do you usually do it in that scenario?

Comment: Hey, sadly I haven't got a machine in front of me to try and help you out however try having a look within the registry under... HKLM\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.ini\MyODBCKey ... see if you can spot the one your after set in here then it can be exported and imported with ease for multiple machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the way.

Using MS Query instead of ODBC from within Excel. Is a bit tricky as it needs to open another app, pick mock columns, return the data and import back to Excel, and then take profit of that DSN is automatically populated to change that connection String password and the query itself from the table properties.

Anyway, one must have the particular ODBC driver for which the connection is defined installed in its computer, but at least we don't need to define the source connection for each end user.